# How to install a web server on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, tasksel

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install tasksel

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Package tasksel is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'tasksel' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: first update your repositories(`sudo apt-get update`) and then try again.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'll get the full download if you try another mirror (e.g. via desktop by changing the settings which become available in the software updater app after it has checked for updates).

I found the following commands worked for me directly after a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 (*trusty*):

```
username@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install tasksel
username@ubuntu:~$ sudo tasksel install lamp-server 
username@ubuntu:~$ webbrowser-app http://localhost
```

Comment: Read the question carefully. The first command is what fails for the OP.

Comment: yes it does, and my answer tells them to try the commands _after_ checking for updates and trying another mirror.  Read my answer carefully.

Comment: You are right. I should have read your answer more carefully. My apologies.